# For statement echoing DO ( commands ) in console when batch script runs

Tags: batch-file, echo

Basically when I am running this script, after runprog.exe returns (echos in cmd prompt) everytihng in the do ( ) section.

```
@echo off
set NODES=(server1.com server2.com)
for %%i in %NODES% do (
    echo Log stuff... >> logfile.txt
    runprog.exe /switch %%i
    if %ERRORLEVEL%==0 (echo success) else (echo fail)
    sleep 5
)
```

Edit: @echo off is at the top of the script.

Comment: did you try `@echo off`?

Comment: @echo off is set in the top.

Comment: Perhaps your `Log stuff...` evaluates to `on` at some point, so it gets interpreted as `echo on`.

Comment: @MikeNakis What do you mean 'evaluates' to on? I had an idea regarding that.. I tried to put echo off within my do statement at the top as well as atsign to supress the commands in the do statement ex. atsign echo. When I did that, it displayed blank lines for every line in the do statement.

Comment: Well, in MS-DOS batch files, instead of 'evaluates to' it is more correct to say 'expands to'.  What I mean is that obviously, your statement does not exactly say `echo Log stuff...`, it says something else, which you have omitted because it is probably irrelevant.  However, if this something else happens to be the text `on`, (or if it is something which somehow gets translated to `on`,) then the statement will be interpreted as `echo on`, thus turning echo on.

Comment: Interesting point. Although the first line within the `do ()` is `echo. >> %AUTOLOG%

Comment: It looks like you have posted a summary of your code, and not the actual code. I'm going to assume that `runprog.exe` is not the actual name of the program you are executing. If that program is actually a batch file, then it will cause the problem you are seeing. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/12077525/1012053 for a similar question, along with my accepted answer that explains what is happening.

Comment: @MikeNakis: that isn't a "MS-DOS" batch file. That's a Windows batch file.

Comment: What is `sleep`?  Another batch file? What does _that_ contain?

Comment: Please post your code by cutting and pasting. Summarising often obscures problems. Is your `.exe` truly an `.exe`? have you tried `start`ing it? What is `sleep`? Are you aware that `if %ERRORLEVEL%==0` will use the value of `errorlevel` as it was when the `for` command was parsed, not the changed value returned by your `.exe`? Too many questions to provide an adequate response . Why not post a sample of the screen output - just a couple of loops from the beginning Please edit this into your question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name well, of course the specific batch file at hand is a Windows batch file, but when speaking of the name of a general concept in the parsing and executing of these batch files, (string expansion,) it is not wrong to mention MS-DOS, because this concept has been in place since MS-DOS.

Comment: @MikeNakis: MS-DOS did not have string expansion remotely similar to what Windows does.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in this `sleep 5` command: it is a custom batch file that you have.

The funny thing is that if I run your batch file on my computer the exact same thing is happening, and I most probably have a different 'sleep' batch file than you.  Mine contains the following:

```
@echo off
ping -n %1 127.0.0.1 > NUL 2>&1
```

Replacing `sleep 5` with `call sleep 5` fixes the problem here.

I have no idea why.  Ask Microsoft.

Comment: Adding <pre>call sleep 5</pre> or commenting does not work. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, perhaps the batch file contains `@echo on`.  Did you check it?

Comment: I declared @echo off at the top. I also attempted to re-declare it on the top line of the do ().

Comment: Sorry, no, I meant `sleep.bat`.

Comment: @LEEMAN what you could also try is replace your 'sleep' command (whether it is a batch file or not) with a sleep.bat having the same contents as my sleep.bat and invoking it with 'call' as I do.  If it works for me, it should work for you, too.

Answer (score 0):

As Mike Nakis said, it's the batch file `sleep`.
It's not important if `sleep.bat` contains `@echo off` or not.

The problem is that starting a batch file from another batch file  transfers the control to the new batch file but doesn't return to the caller.

But in your case you have a `FOR-loop` which is completly cached by the cmd.exe.
That's the cause why the first batch doesn't stops immediately.
But when the second loop runs, the cmd.exe has leaved the `batch-file-mode` and is now in the `cmd-line-mode`.

You could control this by adding an echo line.

```
@echo off
set "world="  -- unset the world variable
for /L %%n in (1 1 3) do @(
  call echo Hello %%n %%world%%
  sleep.bat 1
)
```

The output will be

> 1 Hello
>   2 Hello %world%
>   3 Hello %world%

That's because the cmd-line-mode doesn't remove percent expansions when the variable is unset.

The `CALL sleep.bat` solves the problem, as then control simply returns to the caller, as expected.